# Latency when pausing/stopping WaveAudioStream

Tags: java, multithreading, delay, wav

I have just found the code to a [small WAV player](http://www.fobec.com/CMS/java/class/wav-player-avec-bouton-stop-barre-progression_1106.html).

It works well but when clicking the "Pause" and "Stop" buttons there's like a 2 seconds delay which makes the app look really unprofessional. I have no idea what is causing this but I'd really like to have it fixed, could anyone inspect the code and tell me where it comes from? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this sample for a time and don't remember very well.

In my opinion the latency comes mainly from the update frame functions. In the class VisualPlayer, UI are update by a timer which pick up the current values from the thread. It's not very efficient but faster for write this sample.
The best way to update UI is implementing a Runnable class and call it with SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Also have you try to reduce read buffer size ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried reducing the buffer size but it didn't fix it. Your answer is probably right but I don't know enough about those classes you mention so I'm going to stay with what I have. Thanks for writing the player btw ;)